# Optimization of HLSL shader

Tags: optimization, xna, shader, hlsl, pixel-shader

I have the problem that the below pixel shader (HLSL) compiles to **68** instructions (with the below suggested optimizations). However, I would like to use it with shader model 2 and therefore unfortunately I can only use up to **64** instructions. Does anyone see any possible optimizations without changing the result of the shader?

The shader transforms a more-or-less spherical region of the screen (with sinus-shaped borders) from RGB to a gradient of white -> red -> black with some additional brightness etc. modifications.

The shader code is:

```
// Normalized timefactor (1 = fully enabled)
float timeFactor;

// Center of "light"
float x;
float y;

// Size of "light"
float viewsizeQ;
float fadesizeQ;

// Rotational shift
float angleShift;

// Resolution
float screenResolutionWidth;
float screenResolutionHeight;
float screenZoomQTimesX;

// Texture sampler
sampler TextureSampler : register(s0);

float4 method(float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
// New color after transformation
float4 newColor;

// Look up the texture color.
float4 color = tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord);

// Calculate distance
float2 delta = (float2(x, y) - texCoord.xy)
             * float2(screenResolutionWidth, screenResolutionHeight);

// Get angle from center
float distQ = dot(delta, delta) - sin((atan2(delta.x, delta.y) + angleShift) * 13) * screenZoomQTimesX;

// Within fadeSize
if (distQ < fadesizeQ)
{
   // Make greyscale
   float grey = dot(color.rgb, float3(0.3, 0.59, 0.11));

   // Increase contrast by applying a color transformation based on a quasi-sigmoid gamma curve
   grey = 1 / (1 + pow(1.25-grey/2, 16) );

   // Transform Black/White color range to Black/Red/White color range
   // 1 -> 0.5f ... White -> Red
   if (grey >= 0.75)
   {
   newColor.r = 0.7 + 0.3 * color.r;
   grey = (grey - 0.75) * 4;
   newColor.gb = 0.7 * grey + 0.3 * color.gb;
   }
   else // 0.5f -> 0 ... Red -> Black
   {
   newColor.r = 1.5 * 0.7 * grey + 0.3 * color.r;
   newColor.gb = 0.3 * color.gb ;
   }

   // Within viewSize (Full transformation, only blend with timefactor)
   if (distQ < viewsizeQ)
   {
 color.rgb = lerp(newColor.rgb, color.rgb, timeFactor);
   }
   // Outside viewSize but still in fadeSize (Spatial fade-out but also with timefactor)
   else
   {
      float factor = timeFactor * (1 - (distQ  - viewsizeQ) / (fadesizeQ - viewsizeQ));
      color.rgb = lerp(newColor.rgb, color.rgb, factor);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Few bits and pieces also, you have x,y for light center + screen width /height.

Replacing by :

```
float2 light;
float2 screenResolution;
```

Then in your code:

```
float2 delta = (light - texCoord.xy) * screenResolution;
```

Should remove 2 more instructions.

Next is the use of atan2, which is likely to be the most hungry one.

You can declare another float2 (float2 vecshift), where x = cos(AngleShift) and y = sin(angleShift). Just precompute this one in CPU.

Then you can do the following (basically do a cross product to extract angle instead of using atan2):

```
float2 dn = normalize(delta);
float cr = dn.x *vecshift.y -dn.y * vecshift.x;
float distQ = dot(delta, delta) - sin((asin(cr))*13) *screenZoomQTimesX;
```

Please note than I'm not too keen on sin of asin of something, but polynomial form would not fit in your use case. I'm sure there's a much cleaner version to modulate than using sin*asin tho ))

Using ? construct instead of if/else can also (sometimes) help for your instruction count.

```
color.rgb = lerp(newColor.rgb, color.rgb, distQ < viewsizeQ ? timeFactor : timeFactor * (1 - (distQ  - viewsizeQ) / (fadesizeQ - viewsizeQ)));
```

Does reduce 2 more instructions.

Full version here, sets to 60 instructions.

```
// Normalized timefactor (1 = fully enabled)
float timeFactor;

float2 light;

float viewsizeQ;
float fadesizeQ;

float2 screenResolution;
float screenZoomQTimesX;

float2 vecshift;

// Texture sampler
sampler TextureSampler : register(s0);

float4 method(float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
// New color after transformation
float4 newColor;

// Look up the texture color.
float4 color =tex2D(Samp, texCoord);

// Calculate distance
float2 delta = (light - texCoord.xy) * screenResolution;

float2 dn = normalize(delta);
float cr = dn.x *vecshift.y -dn.y * vecshift.x;

float distQ = dot(delta, delta) - sin((asin(cr))*13) *screenZoomQTimesX;
//float distQ = dot(delta, delta) - a13 *screenZoomQTimesX;

if (distQ < fadesizeQ)
{
   // Make greyscale
   float grey = dot(color.rgb, float3(0.3, 0.59, 0.11));

   // Increase contrast by applying a color transformation based on a quasi-sigmoid gamma curve
   grey = 1 / (1 + pow(1.25-grey/2, 16) );

   // Transform Black/White color range to Black/Red/White color range
   // 1 -> 0.5f ... White -> Red
   if (grey >= 0.75)
   {
       newColor.r = 0.7 + 0.3 * color.r;
       grey = (grey - 0.75) * 4;
       newColor.gb = 0.7 * grey + 0.3 * color.gb;
   }
   else // 0.5f -> 0 ... Red -> Black
   {
       newColor.r = 1.5 * 0.7 * grey + 0.3 * color.r;
       newColor.gb = 0.3 * color.gb ;
   }

   color.rgb = lerp(newColor.rgb, color.rgb, distQ < viewsizeQ ? timeFactor : timeFactor * (1 - (distQ  - viewsizeQ) / (fadesizeQ - viewsizeQ)));
}
return color;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

A couple of suggestions

- You could use a 1D sampler (as a lookup table) for your quasi-sigmoid. If `power` goes from 0 to 1, then create a texture of 1 x 256 (or whatever horizontal size preserves your function best) and simply look up a value for your current `power` using [tex1D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You will need to run this function on the CPU to fill in this texture, but it would just be done once during load time.
- You could use the [lerp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function instead of spelling it out as `color.rgb = /*0.7 */ factor * newColor.rgb + /*0.3 **/ (1 - factor) * color.rgb;` instead, use `color.rgb = lerp(newColor.rgb, color.rgb, factor);` (lerp generally compiles down to an assembly instruction on most GPUs), saving you instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! How do I implement a lookup-table in HLSL - could you give me an example? Which part of the above code can be optimized by the lerp instruction?

Comment: Added explanations as part of the answer above.

Comment: Thanks, the lerp (included now in the above shader code) saved one instruction which gets us to 68 (from 69).

Comment: Did you try the lookup table? That ought to take it down some more.

Comment: Not yet, but I will try this soon.

Answer (score 1):

Using a couple more lerps I was able to get it below 64 instructions. The lookup table didn't help as atan2 actually lead to fewer instructions than looking up the texture.

```
// Normalized timefactor (1 = fully enabled)
float timeFactor;

// Center of "light"
float x;
float y;

// Size of "light"
float viewsizeQ;
float fadesizeQ;

// Rotational shift
float angleShift;

// Resolution
float screenResolutionWidth;
float screenResolutionHeight;
float screenZoomQTimesX;

// Texture sampler
sampler TextureSampler : register(s0);

float4 method(float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
float4 newColor;

// Look up the texture color.
float4 color = tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord);

// Calculate distance
float2 delta = (float2(x, y) - texCoord.xy)
             * float2(screenResolutionWidth, screenResolutionHeight);

// Get angle from center
float distQ = dot(delta, delta) - sin((atan2(delta.x, delta.y) + angleShift) * 13) * screenZoomQTimesX;

// Outside fadeSize: No color transformation
if (distQ >= fadesizeQ) return color;

// Otherwise (within color transformed region) /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Make greyscale
float grey = dot(color.rgb, float3(0.3, 0.59, 0.11));

// Increase contrast by applying a color transformation based on a quasi-sigmoid gamma curve
grey = 1 / (1 + pow(1.25-grey/2, 16));

// Transform greyscale to white->red->black gradient
// 1 -> 0.5f ... White -> Red
if (grey >= 0.5)
{
newColor = lerp(float4(0.937,0.104,0.104,1), float4(1,1,1,1), 2 * (grey-0.5)
}
else // 0.5f -> 0 ... Red -> Black
{
newColor = lerp(float4(0,0,0,1), float4(0.937,0.104,0.104,1), 2 * grey);
}

float factor = saturate(timeFactor * (1 - (distQ  - viewsizeQ) / (fadesizeQ - viewsizeQ)));
color.rgb = lerp(color.rgb, newColor.rgb, factor);

return color;
 }
```